# How to control TAB key press event on NSPopUpButton programmatically

Tags: macos, xcode5.1, nspopupbutton

I'm developing an app for MacOSX with Xcode5

I want to control when I press tab over a NSPopUpButton selected, I made my own subclass of NSPopUpButton named MyNSPopUpButton and put this:

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeKeyView{
    return YES;
}
```

Now I can't select my NSPopupButtons by pressing Tab key, but also I want to control where to go from there, on NSTextFields I use this method:

```
-(BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector{

    NSTextField     *textField  = (NSTextField *) control;

    if (commandSelector == @selector(insertTab:) ||
        commandSelector == @selector(insertNewline:)) {


        if (textField == _diaTextField) {
            [self.window makeFirstResponder:_cantidadDebeTextField];
        }

        if (textField == _cantidadDebeTextField) {
            [self.window makeFirstResponder:_cuentaDebePopupButton];
        }

        if (textField == _cantidadHaberTextField) {
            [self.window makeFirstResponder:_descripcionAsientoTextField];
        }

        if (textField == _descripcionAsientoTextField) {
            [self.window makeFirstResponder:_descripcionBitacoraTextField];
        }

        if (textField == _descripcionBitacoraTextField) {
            [self.window makeFirstResponder:nil];
        }

        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

As you can see there I'm controlling the navigation with TAB key, I want to do the same with NSPopUpButtons but I can't even set any delegate of them like with NSTextFields,

I know I can do this by setting their tags number in the proper order but I'll be adding more controls on runtime programmatically

is there a way to control this from code???

thanks for the support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You turn off `autorecalculatesKeyViewLoop` on the window and set the key view loop yourself. You do that by setting the `nextKeyView` property of all of your views. They should form a loop.

You probably want to set the `initialFirstResponder` of your window, too.

When you add a view, you'll need to adjust the key view loop to include it in the desired position.

Comment: autorecalculatesKeyViewLoop I have it as off by default, also I have my first view [_diaTextField becomeFirstResponder]; when I load my view, and the key View loop when is static, it has the proper order, but when I add more controls it loses the order, that's why I need to set the order programmatically there, with NSTextFields everything works good, but I can't set the order with NSPopupButtons programmatically :(

Comment: First, you should never call `-becomeFirstResponder` (except to call `super` within an override). See the docs for that method on `NSResponder`. Either set the window's `initialFirstResponder` or call `-[NSWindow makeFirstResponder:]`. Next, if you add or remove views from the window, and you're managing the key view loop manually, you need to call `-setNextKeyView:` as appropriate to incorporate the new views or close any gaps left by removing views. The technique you showed for text fields is a very roundabout way and won't work in the general case. Setting `nextKeyView` will work.